# USBHIDManager HID, getReport() and setReport() On Mac Environment

Tags: cocoa, usb, hid, iokit, kernel-extension

We are trying to communicate with a USB HIDDevice. This device is working fine in windows, where we can send a report and get a report back using `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()`.

On the Mac, we are trying to interface with the device using `setReoprt()` and `getReport()`. But `getReport()` is not returning any data, but an error.

What is the wrong in the application?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the code you’re using and the error message(s)?

Comment: There is no Error message and  no valid data for GetReport(). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In order to make use of asynchronous behavior, the event source obtained using getAsyncEventSource must be added to a run loop.***

The above note is part of the comment of setReport. U might need to learn the runloop mechanism of Runloop in Mac OS first.

Since it's impossible to explain the mechanism here. The following functions and orders might help u coding when u get familiar with **RunLoop**.(Try to search "CFRunLoop" in google)

*CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

CFRunLoopRun();

CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopRef rl, CFRunLoopSourceRef source, CFStringRef mode);

CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopRef rl);(i usually call this function in the callback method)*

Comment: Thanks. Mydevice discription is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834101/no-kernel-file-specified-error-on-kext-mac-environment . This is HID Device ( HIDManager Concept), so i try to retrieve data Using getReport, My program is working fine for Key Board And Mouse,So my Doubts are: 1) How to send interrept to end poing 2)if i send interrupt to end point can i get Data ,(I thing my runloope Working Fine),

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727363/iohiddevicegetreportwithcallback-function-do-not-work-in-my-cocoa-application