# No kernel file specified Error On KEXT MAC Environment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, device-driver, iokit, kernel-extension

I try implement KEXT for USBHID Device. If i am checking on Terminal It able to load KEXT ie
        Newtok:Desktop Rasheed$ kextutil -nt  SampleKextDriver.kext
        No kernel file specified; using running kernel for linking.
        SampleKextDriver.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
        But Unfortunately I Got the above Message. My plist File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <string>English</string>
            <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
            <string>SampleKextDriver</string>
            <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.dts.driver.SampleKextDriver</string>
            <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
            <string>6.0</string>
            <key>CFBundleName</key>
            <string>Mustahfa</string>
            <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
            <string>KEXT</string>
            <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
            <string>????</string>
            <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Device Driver</key>
                <dict>            
                    <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.apple.dts.driver.SampleKextDriver</string>
                    <key>IOMatchingCategory</key>
                    <string>com_apple_dts_driver_SampleKextDriver</string>
                    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                    <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
                    <key>idProduct</key>
                    <integer>4389</integer>
                    <key>idVendor</key>
                    <integer>8192</integer>
                    <key>IOClass</key>
                    <string>IOService</string>
                    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                    <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily</key>
                <string>1.6.4</string>
                <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
                <string>10.7</string>
                <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
                <string>10.7</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        </plist>
```

I don't know where i Did Wrong ,I do not have much experience in Mac OS X development. Can anyone please suggest the best documents or some Idea

Thanks for your information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.U should not using -n option when loading your kext.
The -n option for **kextutil** seems used to generate the symbol file only.
The -t option for **kextutil** print the failed reason when error occurs.
For more details about **kextutil**, u should type ***man kextutil*** in the **Terminal**.

2.I suggest u to open the Terminal and type follow commands to determine the version of the Kexts your driver depends on. (Of course, u should specify the lowest version of the system your driver needs to support.)

*kextstat |grep com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily

kextstat |grep com.apple.kpi.iokit

kextstat |grep com.apple.kpi.libkern*

then update the OSBundleLibraries dictionary of your driver's info.plist.

3.Hope this is useful for u. Have a good day!